# Spectral radiance and energy of oscillation

Tags: thermodynamics

The outgoing long wave IR spectral radiance graph by wavelength shows the spectral radiance of IR increasing as wavelength goes from 5 microns to 10 microns but the energy of oscillation goes down over the whole spectrum from gamma rays to radiowaves. What is the diff between energy of oscillation and spectral radiance? They are both in units of energy, so how can 1 be going up while the other is going down?

Comment: The graph has a peak on the eigenfrequency of the material in temperature T.Oscillation frequency is close but not equal to radiation frequency.

Comment: If oscillation frequency is directly proportional to energy level ie the longer wave lengths have less energy than the shorter ones, then how can the spectral radiance increase as wavelength goes up in the spectral radiance graph with wavelength as independent variable and spectral radiance on the y axis?

Comment: Initially goes up.Can you link this graph?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281423687_Using_IASI_to_simulate_the_total_spectrum_of_outgoing_long-wave_radiances   Notice that in Figure 13 as wavenumber goes from 1500/cm to 800/cm or in wavelength terms goes from 6.6 to 12.5 microns, the spectral radiancegoes up. How can the spectral radiance go up but the energy of oscillation in ev goes down as you go from gamma rays to radio waves.

Comment: Every compound has a featured emission as well an absorption spectrum due to its molecular structure.The thermal motion of the molecules is other.

Comment: I realize that in Figure 13, it is an emission spectrum and I was comparing it to an absorption spectrum. Irregardless of emission and absorption, how can one energy be going down as wavelength increases(energy of oscillation) and  at the same time go up as wavelength increases as in Figure 13?

Comment: Every chemical bond has many oscillations (bend,stretch,swing,twist,swirl),and every compound has many chemical bonds.

Comment: But that still doesnt explain how 1 measure of energy can be going up by wavelength and the other measure(energy of oscillation) of energy  is going down.

Comment: Specify what you mean as "energy of oscillation".Thermal motion? Energy is not given by Planck equation.

Comment: Energy of oscillation (ev) is the total energy of a molecule or lightwave. Gamma rays and x rays have much higher ev with a low wavelength whereas radio waves have much lower ev with a high wavelength. That is opposite to the emissions Modtran graphs that show radiance increasing as you go from low wavelength to high wavelength on the right side of the curve.

Comment: Read about black body radiation http://how-it-looks.blogspot.com/2010/01/infrared-radiation-black-bodies-and.html